# Checking if innerText of class is defined or not

Tags: javascript, undefined, setinterval, innertext

I have a js script, which is extracting the innertext of a class. Sometimes that class is not rendered on the webpage, so for that case, innertext comes undefined. I want to keep a check for this so that this error is omitted.
This is the code that I wrote ->

```
function myfunc() {          
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
    if (button[0].innerText !== undefined) {   
        console.log(button[0].innerText);
        clearInterval(x);
    } 
}

var x = setInterval(function() {
    myfunc();
}, 1)
```

So for the cases when the class is not there on the page, I was getting an undefined error hence I want to check that. I used an if condition in the code by checking if it is `!== undefined` but that is not working. Can anyone suggest some other methods? The error that I was getting ->

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined
```

Comment: `if(button[0]) {...}` will probably work. At the moment you're trying to access the text of an element that doesn't exist for your condition.

Comment: Or try using `button[0]?.innerText` (notice the ?) This first checks if button[0] exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work, because `document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')` returns 0 buttons, so `button[0]` is already undefined.

You can solve this problem by using **optional chaining**:

```js
if(button[0]?.innerText !== undefined){
```

The value on the left side is automatically undefined if something before the `?` is undefined.

If `button[0]` doesn't exist / is undefined, JS won't even try to get the `innerText` property.

### Or even easier

Just check the length:

```js
if(button.length > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check that `button[0]` exists before trying `innerText` on it. I cleaned it up a bit, but this should do the trick:

```js
function checkForButton() {
   const button = document.querySelector('.myclass');
   if (button && button.textContent) {
     console.log(button.textContent);
     clearInterval(x);
   }
}
```